# Unlocking phone opens app

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, unlock

Very frequently, trying to unlock my phone (slide from bottom up) will open an app that has a notification instead of just unlocking my phone. How do I make it stop and only unlock the phone when I'm using the unlock gesture?

Haptic Touch is on medium, and even considering that the touch duration is on 'fast', it's still feels slow on the test on that menu, so I don't think that that's the problem.

I disabled the 'raise to wake' option so there was less chance of me clicking on a notification by accident instead of unlocking, but the phone still opens notifications occasionally. I'm waking the phone by double tapping on the screen and then using my thumb to slide a bit from the bottom, and moving only a quarter screen up from the bottom, so definitely not all the way to the top.

That sure is being a huge inconvenience for me, as it's opening apps I don't want to open and marking notifications as read even though I didn't see them (as I'm busy and couldn't check it)

Details: iPhone Xs, iOS 14.6, happens with Twitter, Reddit, imgur

Comment: It would be helpful to add the version of iOS on your iPhone and the name of the app that is doing this. Please https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/424116/edit EDIT your answer rather than responding in a comment.

Comment: ooohhhhh, you might be right
Because it takes a moment for it to wake up, I was doing double-tap. So maybe that's what was happening. Thank you!